# How to change the port number using which prometheus scrapes metrcs

Tags: akka, prometheus, metrics, prometheus-operator

I have a pod with replication factor of 3. The app puts metrics on port `9001`. I would like prometheus operator to scrape the metrics. I have the following in my `values.yaml` when using stable/prometheus-operator helm chart.

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
    - job_name: 'akka-metrics'
      scrape_interval: 15s
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
        namespaces:
          names:
          - default
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
        action: keep   
        regex: 'my_pod_name.*'
```

Using the setting above, I can see the pod in `/target` but it is trying to get metrics from port `2551` and `8558`. I would like to change on of these ports to `9001` (the actual port where my app spits metrics). I am wondering how I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a [relabelling rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config):

```
- job_name: 'akka-metrics'
      scrape_interval: 15s
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
        namespaces:
          names:
          - default
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name]
        action: keep   
        regex: 'my_pod_name.*'
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        action: replace
        regex: ([^:]+):.*
        replacement: $1:9001
        target_label: __address__
```

The last rule modifies the `__address__` label of the target. It extracts the IP address and sets the port to 9001. This should cause Prometheus to always use `<ip>:9001` as the target.

Something similar is used in the official [example scrape config for Kubernetes](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml#L269).